# Setting up Detox with Expo on Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo, detox

I'm trying to set up Detox with Expo on Android emulator (Genymotion) but I have an error that I can't go through....

I've installed the necessary packages :

- Detox
- detox-expo-helpers
- expo-detox-hook

Downloaded the Exponent.apk on the official expo site

set up my package.json :

```
"detox": {
    "test-runner": "jest",
    "configurations": {
      "android": {
        "binaryPath": "bin/Exponent.apk",
        "build": "npm run android",
        "type": "android.attached",
        "device": {
          "adbName": "192.168.58.101:5555"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Set up the config.json on the e2e folder :

```
{
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./init.ts"],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "reporters": ["detox/runners/jest/streamlineReporter"],
    "verbose": true
}
```

Set up my init.ts file :

```
import {cleanup, init} from "detox";
import * as adapter from "detox/runners/jest/adapter";

const config = require("../package.json").detox;

jest.setTimeout(120000);
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(adapter);

beforeAll(async () => {
    await init(config);
});

beforeEach(async () => {
    await adapter.beforeEach();
});

afterAll(async () => {
    await adapter.afterAll();
    await cleanup();
});
```

When I run the tests with `detox test` I've the following error :

> Error: '.../androidTest/Exponent/Exponent-androidTest.apk' could not
>   be found, did you run './gradlew assembleAndroidTest' ?

How is generated this androidTest file with Expo ?
Did I made something wrong ?

**EDIT :**

I've also try to use the .sh script to fetch the Exponent.apk file :

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# query expo.io to find most recent ipaUrl
IPA_URL=`curl https://expo.io/--/api/v2/versions |  python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["androidUrl"]'`

# download tar.gz
TMP_PATH=bin/Exponent.apk
wget -O $TMP_PATH $IPA_URL
```

Comment: Hi, did you follow exactly the steps on : https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.Android.md?

Comment: I'm using expo, so I don't have a gradle file...

Comment: yes missed that, did you follow a tutorial like: https://blog.expo.io/testing-expo-apps-with-detox-and-react-native-testing-library-7fbdbb82ac87

Comment: It works only on iOS emulator... :( Would like to make it on android emulator

Comment: I think if you really want to run on android emulator try to migrate your project to a raw react-native project an follow the installation from the Detox get started

Comment: Did you actually run `detox build`

Comment: @Black there is no build command for the Expo setup.

OP can you share what you have for iOS as mine is not running the tests in the emulator it eventually times out. Would appreciate if you could share.

Comment: Late to the party ... But did you managed to get this working ? Your post have already so much data I didn't have ... What king of tuorial did you follow ? I can only find things for iOS  :(

Comment: 1 year and half after, I doesn't have the solution yet. But since expo 42 let you manage custom native librairies, maybe we can found a solution there. I'll try when we'll have access to EAS build. About these data, I forgot where they came from... let work together to make it works !!

Comment: Hi, did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Nop, i'm not even sure it is possible...

Comment: Did anyone figure this out? I can't believe that is is not possible to do proper e2e testing using expo on the Android simulator...

Comment: Nohing new since this time... :/

Answer (score -1):

Try cleaning the gradle file by

> cd android
> ./gradlew clean

and then re-run the app like this:

> cd ..
> npm start

Comment: I didn't ejected from expo, so I haven't that android folder.